# Unable to connect to a remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-22.04

I am unable to connect to a remote mysql server. Both my remote and local machines are using ubuntu. The remote is a machine hosted in aws ec2 instance.

I have changed the remote's bind-address in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` like so:

> bind-address=0.0.0.0

I have created a new remote user `CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and granted necessary permissions like so:

> GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'username'@'%';

followed By `sudo service mysql restart`.
I have changed firewall settings like so:

> sudo ufw allow 3306

But I am still unable to connect from my local ubuntu machine or other ec2 instances. I have done `telnet 13.127.232.87 3306` but it results in timeout but I have also check remote with `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` which is showing to be running perfectly. There are no errors in log but says :

```
Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-05-21T07:18:42.452577Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-05-21T07:18:42.452831Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

EDIT:
Also tried: `sshd: <IP_addresses_to_whitelist>` followed by `sudo service ssh restart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has same problem in the future follow all the above steps one by one and don't forget to allow 3306 on security group not as type tcp but as mysql that was kind of embarrasing mistake on my part.  :)

Comment: Could you please share more information ?
In which security group?

Comment: @johntriantafillakis the security group which is connected to the aws instance in question.